# How do you implement variable-length recurrent neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

What is a full working example (not snippets) of variable-length sequence inputs into recurrent neural networks (RNNs)?

For example PyTorch supposedly can implement variable-length sequences as input into RNNs, but there do not seem to be examples of full working code.

Relevant:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.1.10
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-the-variable-length-input-in-rnn-scenario/345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such thing as 'variable length' neural networks. This is because there is no way a network can 'know' which weights to use for extra input nodes that it wasn't trained for.

However, the reason you are seeing a 'variable length' on that page, is because they process:

```
a b c d e
a b c d e f g h
a b c d
a b
```

as

```
a b c d e 0 0 0
a b c d e f g h
a b c d 0 0 0 0
a b 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

They convert all 'empty' variables to `0`. Which makes sense, as `0` does not add anything tot he networks hidden layers regardless of the weights, as `anything*0 = 0`.

So basically, you can have 'variable length' inputs, but you have to define some kind of maximum size; all inputs that are smaller than that size should be padded with zeros.

If you are classifying sentences on the other hand, you could use LSTM/GRU networks to handle the input sequentially.

Comment: What you've written is partially incorrect. RNN's are meant to handle variable inputs. Its not the network's limitation, but rather the limitation of the tensor (as designed by pytorch). You can still pass variable input to an RNN in pytorch if you do a single sample per training step ( by making batch size = 1), without any padding. Padding comes into play if you want to process a mini-batch, and since a tensor cannot technically have any of its dimension be of variable size, you have to resort to padding.

Comment: This did not answer the question.  Clearly there is support for variable length sequences into RNNs, per the website: "nn.RNN, nn.LSTM, nn.GRU now support mini-batches where sequences are of variable lengths."

Comment: variable length input in recurrent neural net is not referring to the size of each sample being variable, but the size of sequences of equal length inputs being variable. Imagine learning sequences of words - you need to reset the weights when switching to a new sentence. Sentences can be of variable lengths

Comment: @RaduSimionescu what do you mean by `the size of sequences of equal length inputs being variable`? "cat is big", "dog is small" - these 2 sequences have equal length input(3 words). What does size of sequences mean here again?

Comment: this was a long time ago heh. @theprogrammer, I think I was trying to say that, even though RNNs can take a variable number of tokens during prediction, for training you will have to establish some size of tokens per sentence and do some padding as needed, in order to represent a set of training sentences of different sizes as one big fat tensor. You will want to feed training data in batches to your whatever framework, otherwise training will be slow.